# What is the next step after received acceptance from the Editor

Tags: journals

I received an acceptance from the Editor by email, but when I checked the status of my manuscript in the journal website it is "Editor Decision", even after week of receiving the email.

what does that mean? and should I talk to the Editor?

Comment: If you got a written email from the editor that you were accepted, then the simplest answer to the discrepancy is that he hasn't updated the website. Maybe he's got a stack of a dozen or so papers he wants to update all at once?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will write an email to them and see what is the issue.

Comment: "Editor Decision" may also mean that the editor has decided, i.e., to accept.  You got the letter saying you're accepted, you're fine.

Comment: I found that the best way is to send email to the Editor. and I did. he replied that there are some difficulties on the website. Thank to all of you for advices, suggestions, and comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the editor emails you an acceptance, the paper is accepted.  Don't worry about the website not updating.

The acceptance email should contain instructions as to what you have to do next: presumably, make any changes suggested by the reviewers and submit a final version of your manuscript.  If it doesn't, wait another week or so to see if you get an email that does have the instructions (this might be sent automatically by the management system when the editor updates it). If not, email the editor then.

Comment: I just received an email told me that "your revised version of your paper  has now been accepted for publication in (Journal name)" without any further instructions. is this is the official acceptance?

Comment: @Hugo: That certainly looks like an acceptance to me.  It's possible that the version you submitted is already suitable as a final version for typesetting.  In that case, all you need to do is wait for them to send the typeset proofs after the paper is assigned to an issue.  If you are unsure, it is fine to ask the editor, but again I would wait a week or so in case they are already planning to send you something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Talk to them. Hanging out fretting about it only causes yourself undue stress. I would simply write an email to them... It sounds like the "switch" may be a manual one on their web site? Perhaps the programmer/designer is on holiday break?

Remember... the individual maintaining the status or entries themselves may not be the actual web master in charge of the programming and edits on the site. It's probably an entirely different department and the batch of edit tickets to the site have yet to process.

Still, even if the individual who sent the email **IS** the one in charge of the web site...I'd trust the letter over the web site any day.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will write an email to them and see what is the issue.

Comment: why the DV? Seems same concept as the accepted answer... web site isn't updated. Emailing them to verify is *not* a bad thing to do.

Comment: @Jukka: An hour before the accepted answer posted = "...I'd trust the letter over the web site any day."